# Async Task not firing

Tags: c#, asynchronous, parse-platform, async-await, wait

I have an `async task` method that I am calling on page load, it is successfully entering into the method, but it "freezes" on a line which I will point out below and I can not figure out why.

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     ParseClient.Initialize("AppKey", ".NetKey");

     Load().Wait();
 }    

 public async Task Load()
 {
     ParseQuery<ParseObject> myQuery = ParseObject.GetQuery("myClass");
     IEnumerable<ParseObject> results = await myQuery.FindAsync();
     foreach (ParseObject result in results)
     {
         string firstName = result.Get<string>("name");
     }
 }
```

It is "freezing" for me on this line:

```
IEnumerable<ParseObject> results = await myQuery.FindAsync();
```

This may be a very rudimentary thing that I am looking over, I just can't seem to find it... Any advice?

Comment: Why should it not freeze? You are calling `Wait` which means "freeze everything until this is done". Can you explain why you thought that calling `Wait` does not wait?

Comment: [Don't block on async code](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) you are likey deadlocking yourself.

Comment: @EricLippert how can I fire the async method in my Page Load method?

Comment: You may want to checkout "Using Asynchronous Methods in ASP.NET 4.5" at http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/performance-and-caching/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-45 I did assume, this is ASP.Net

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have two tasks. The "inner" task is "find some results".  The "outer" task is "get the query, find some results, enumerate the results".

Note that the outer task depends upon the completion of the inner task.

You execute Load. This creates the "outer" task. It then creates the "inner" task and returns.  Why? Because you said to `await` -- an asynchronous wait -- for the inner task to complete.  Therefore you must immediately return control to the caller so that it can continue to do work. The outer task is returned to the caller.

What does the caller do? It says "stop everything until the outer task is done".  Now, tell me, how is that supposed to happen? The thread that is going to execute the remainder of the outer task is at present frozen, waiting for the outer task to complete. You said "thread, do some work asynchronously *and do no work until it is done*".  Well, your wish will be granted; no work will be done and the thread will wait until the work is done, which will be never.

Now, even if by some miracle the inner task completes -- perhaps it is running on another thread -- it must still signal the outer task "the inner task is complete, so you can finish your work now" on the thread that you just froze.

> how can I fire the async method in my Page Load method?

See this page:

http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/performance-and-caching/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-45

Comment: I understand what you are saying now and this may be outside the scope of the question, but could you provide a snippet of syntax that would in my case guide me a little further?

Comment: But wouldn't I need to make the page load method async in that case? If I am awaiting in that method?

Comment: I am new (as you can tell) to the whole asynchronous, synchronous syntax, but is that a good practice to make the page load async?

Comment: @Code: Actually, my (now deleted) advice to make Page_Load async is not great advice; that would be better for a GUI sort of project. I was forgetting that there are special rules for ASP.NET that differ from GUI projects.  For advice on how to handle asynchronous top level events in ASP.NET there is better advice here: http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/performance-and-caching/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-45

Comment: @Code, you can register the `Load` task inside your `Page_Load` code via `RegisterAsyncTask(new PageAsyncTask(Load))`. You do this after `ParseClient.Initialize`. See http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheMagicOfUsingAsynchronousMethodsInASPNET45PlusAnImportantGotcha.aspx

Comment: @EricLippert, re your last paragraph: since it's ASP.NET we're talking about, there is no guarantee that the post-`await` continuation will be scheduled on the same thread (even in the absence of `ConfigureAwait(false)`. You're at the mercy of `AspNetSynchronizationContext`, so the deadlock may or may not happen depending on which thread it decides to run the continuation on.

Comment: @KirillShlenskiy: That is a good point which I was neglecting. I forget that the model is different in ASP.NET than in the UI applications that I more commonly think about when it comes to asynchrony!